# How do you Calculate with floats in c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, integer, unity3d-terrain

I want to programm a terrain generator in Unity and already have some working code for a Perlin Noise Terrain Generator. Im currently using Unity (using c#) and i cant figure out how to seperate the generation of the terrain depth(z)(the height of the mountains/depth of the valleys which i want to calculate using a Sqrt function) depending on x and the terrain depth depending on y. My problem is, when i try to convert the floats into ints, i would have to round them up or else they wont work, but i want to calculate the Terraindepth smoothly, is there a way i can combine those 2 heights into 1 without roughening the terrain?

```
float CalculateHeights(int x, int y)
{
    float xCoord = x;

        private int xz = float xCoord; 

    float yCoord = (float)y / height; 

        private int yz =float yCoord;

    int z = (xz + yz) / 2;

    return Mathf.Sqrt(z);
}
```

Comment: There's a lot going on with this code.
First, you can't specify a "private" modifier within a C# function.
Secondly, what is "height" and where is it declared?
You don't need to specify the variable type when you reference the variable a second time. If you were trying to cast it to a float, you would need to wrap it in parenthesis like you're doing with "(float)y". However, you don't need to cast to a float when it's already a float.
Finally, when you assign the result to an int, you would need to either cast or convert it.

This code won't compile. You'll need to fix its issues first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use Perlin Noise in Unity, you can always use the inbuilt generator.

Ex:

```
float height = Mathf.PerlinNoise(X,Y);
```

Warning though: If you don't use floating point values for X and Y with this function, you'll have issues with always getting the same value.

Hope this helps.

Docs - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html

Comment: Thanks, but im trying to get away from using perlin noise, i want to experiment with other mathematical functions as well, like square ore other stuff, so i want to programm a generator that calculates the x and y direction seperately, so0 im asking for a calculator that makes int x and int y to one int z like that: z = (x + y) / 2 and then i want to use z for a mathematical function.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to get a terrain but therefore i need 2 functions, not one.